# Not retriving data from socket java

Tags: java, sockets

i'm writing a java program that sends and receives data from a printer, i can get the command but i can't read in any way a response.

```
                            Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
                            System.out.println("-----------------> MioSocket closed: "+s.isClosed());
                       
                            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
                            System.out.println("-----------------> InputStream: "+out.toString());
                            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(out);
                            String str = "GST\r";
                            output.writeUTF(str);
                            System.out.println("---->");
                            
                            InputStream input = s.getInputStream();
                            System.out.println("-----------------> InputStream: "+input.toString());
                            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                            System.out.println("-----------------> InputStream: "+reader.toString());
                 
                            int character;
                            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
                            System.out.println(reader.read());
                            while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {
                                data.append((char) character);
                            }
                 
                            System.out.println(data);
                            s.close();
```

Comment: Do you know if the printer even sends a response?

Comment: if I interrogate it from tera term it answers me correctly

Comment: So what happens when you try?

Comment: sending the command to the printer works well, but when I go to read the response, the program crashes.